# How can I make use of bash functions in a makefile?

Tags: make

If I need to use something like NVM in my makefile, I run into a problem, because NVM exports some bash functions that are not available in Make, even if my shell is defined as bash in the makefile.

How do I cause make to "inherit" all the parent shell's functions? Is there a way to make NVM accessible to a makefile, without writing `export -f` for a zillion little NVM bash functions?

Comment: Probably [related](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184508/nvm-command-not-available-in-bash-script).

Comment: indeed. but does not offer a good solution. I can make it work with prepending `source ...` to every line of my makefile, for example, but clearly that's sub-optimal.

Comment: Maybe this may worth a word in your question on what you already tried/found and why it doesn't solve your problem, an example Makefile exhibiting the problem could help aslo I think.

Comment: Btw another [source](https://blog.jayway.com/2013/05/19/auto-install-node-js-and-npm-from-makefile/), I'm not working with node.js so that's just in case it may be of help to solve the problem

Comment: not so much, actually, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: Let me see if I get right: you're problem is to avoid writing `export -f <funcname>` for each nvm function of your parent shell. (if this is the case I assume `declare -F | sed 's/declare/export/' > func.sh` and then a `source funcs.sh` within the makefile should do.)

Comment: This probably belongs on StackOverflow as it is not specifically related to DevOps in any way

Comment: @coderanger I've the feeling SO would redirect to server fault which would redirect to SO. I agree that's 100% programming but I feel it would be badly received on SO or SF/SU

Comment: I'd say this on-topic at SF, SO, or here.  It'd be nice if the OP clarified which functions they want from NVM.

Answer (score 6):

There are several options that can be used here. Maybe one of the easiest is to install each function as a real script in some directory that is added to the path.  Here is how to do this:

First, we choose a path name where to store all these functions, it can be a a directory in our project, where other utility scripts used in our Makefile live. We call it *nvm_install_dir*

Then we write a `_nvm_trampoline` script which use the name it is called as to trigger the right function, and create as many file aliases to `_nvm_trampoline`  as there are functions in the script.  Note the leading underscore, hinting at the “private” character of the script.

This script can go along the lines of

```
#!/bin/sh
. "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"

if [ "${0##*/}" = '_nvm_driver' ]; then
    : NOP
else
    eval "${0##*/}" "$@"
fi
```

Here we use `${0##*/}` to remove any path element from the name under which our script is called.  We install that script under `${nvm_install_dir}` and run once the following utility script:

```
nvm_install_dir='SET-TO-ACTUAL-PARAMETER-VALUE!'
nvm_file="${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"
nvm_trampoline='_nvm_trampoline'

nvm_list_functions()
{
    awk -F'[(][)]' '$1 ~ /^nvm_[^ ]*$/{print($1)}' "${nvm_file}"
}

nvm_install()
{
    nvm_list_functions | {
        while read nvm_function; do
            ln\
                "${nvm_install_dir}/${nvm_driver}"\
                "${nvm_install_dir}/${nvm_function}"
            chmod 755 "${nvm_install_dir}/${nvm_function}"
        done
    }
}

nvm_install
```

It is a good practice to pack the *nvm_install* procedure in a real function instead of just inlining its body in the script, as it gives better testing options. (It is easier to comment out the call to *nvm_install* than the body of the function, if we want to experiment with the script.)

Ater this, the directory pointed to by *nvm_install_dir* is populated with aliases to `_nvm_trampoline` that are executable and delegate their work to the corresponding function. We only need to add this directory to our *PATH* when running *make*.

A second approach would be to generate pseudo commands for each *nvm* functions, with the following script:

```
nvm_file="${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"

nvm_list_functions()
{
    awk -F'[(][)]' '$1 ~ /^nvm_[^ ]*$/{print($1)}' "${nvm_file}"
}

nvm_generate()
{
    nvm_list_functions |  {
        while read nvm_function; do
            nvm_FUNCTION=$(printf '%s' "${nvm_function}" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
            printf '%s=sh -c \047source "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"; %s "$$@"\047 %s\n'\
                   "${nvm_FUNCTION}"\
                   "${nvm_function}"\
                   "${nvm_function}"
        done
    }
}

nvm_generate
```

The output of this program consists of *make* variable assignments

```
NVM_ECHO=sh -c 'source "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"; nvm_echo "$$@"' nvm_echo
NVM_CD=sh -c 'source "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"; nvm_cd "$$@"' nvm_cd
…
NVM_COMMAND_INFO=sh -c 'source "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"; nvm_command_info "$$@"' nvm_command_info
…
```

It can be saved to a file `Makefile.nvm` or `nvmtools.mk` that can be included our Makefiles. Calling the function `nvm_command_info` is done with

```
${NVM_COMMAND_INFO} arg1 arg2 …
```

---

Using a customised bash profile is possible, using the assignment `SHELL=/bin/bash --rcfile PATH-TO-CUSTOM-PROFILE -i` but I would consider this esoteric enough to puzzle the maintenance programmer.

Answer (score 3):

One possible issue is that the NVM install script only writes the commands to set itself up to either `.bash_profile` OR `.bashrc`.  Depending on your systems configuration, it may only be setup for interactive shells, not ones spawned by other programs ([more info](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc)).  Sourcing the nvm setup script can be a good option, as a previous comment noted.  If you have a number of commands to run for 1 make target, look into [.ONESHELL](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html#One-Shell).  Sourcing `$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh` should take care of it.

[Another option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13130922) that invokes bash directly with the interactive flag might work as well.